# shp2pgsql no more AddGeometryColumn() function?

Tags: shp2pgsql

#### Problem:

I encounter a fresh error when using `shp2pgsql` on Ubuntu 18.04.
This commands worked a few months ago:

```
$ sudo shp2pgsql -s 4326 /path/to/myshapefile.shp | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d databasename -U postgres
Field height is an FTDouble with width 31 and precision 15
Shapefile type: PointZ
Postgis type: POINT[4]
Password for user postgres: ************************************
SET
SET
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ERROR:  function addgeometrycolumn(unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT AddGeometryColumn('','myshapefile','geom','4326'...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
(...)
```

#### Question:

Any idea on how to fix this?

#### Environment:

Ubuntu 18.04 64 bits: 5.0.0-37-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux

`SELECT Version();`
`"PostgreSQL 10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit"`

`SELECT postgis_version();`
`"2.4 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1"`

Comment: Control each fields type and try to verify the shapefile with qgis. Other possibility, check encoding.

Comment: are you sure **that** database has postgis installed? Next look in the SQL generated and add the section creating the table.

Comment: You were actually right Ian, I always thought that the postgis installation (as many other psql extensions) were done "once for all databases" and not "per databases", but it seems to be actually the case. Thanks for pointing that out.